# How to protect MacBook Air/Pro from damage, knocks, particulary corners

Tags: macbook-pro, damage, case

I'm interested in preserving the appearance, physical enclosure and function of my MacBook from scrapes and physical damage.

What should I do to protect this type of gear?

This is written as a question-answer pairing / self-answer to help others with my experience but would welcome any further answers, I can accept someone else's other than my own as I have done before!

Comment: Excuse me? Why the negative downvote?!  I think that's awful.  I always put a comment to accompany my voting action as to why I did so. Most of my votes given are upvoted. I do upvote sincerely if the contribution actually is useful. If I don't find it useful, I don't tend to downvote but instead leave a constructive comment. Very occasionally, if I feel really really strongly that a comment is not useful I will downvote,but aim to leave a comment to go with it. How awful & cowardly to downvote without giving a reason. I will leave Meta StackExchange comment about mandatory reason to downvote

Comment: If asked as written and without the self-answer, we would most likely put this on hold due to lack of detail and research (or as a shopping question). What kind of protection do you need (office commute in a big city, field work in the jungle, something else), are there financial constraints, what have you looked at/tried and are not happy with etc.

Comment: PS: As for the mandatory comment when downvoting topic: This has come up quite often both on Meta.AD and on Meta.SE. Have a look at the discussions there.

Comment: Well I have done that! "written and without the self-answer" - I immediately answered after asking the question! "What kind of protection do you need (office commute in a big city, field work in the jungle, something else)" - yes I've mentioned in my comment about conditions while travelling - see "train". "what have you looked at/tried and are not happy with etc" - mentioned other good brands like UAG, mention in general how ineffective many cases are. So: lots of boxes checked (US) / ticked (UK). Tick tick tick, yes, yes yes. Alright?!

Comment: Writing a question when you already know the answer is an art sometimes. Key things to consider is that the question itself must stand on its own without looking at the answer. So please make sure to include all the relevant criteria in the question itself (this also makes it easier for other people to provider their own answer).

Comment: "corners" is the main criterion, and a criteron already supplied.

Comment: well someone appreciates my answer as part of my question-answer, they upvoted it. If it helps people and avoids the stress I had with a previous Mac then I've done my job. Perfectly. Period (US) / Full stop (UK).

Comment: +1 thank you for your input on it, though @nohillside  I don't know whether you've kind of "pinned" you comment to permanent appear as a notification to remind me in my notification in-tray, it now persistently shows a white "1" on red circle relating to your comment about the art of posting!

Comment: Wave the "upvoted" flag when it has been upvoted 100 times... 1 vote could be a simple clicking error...

Comment: The system starts to prioritize upvoted comments once there are too many comments to show at once :-)

Comment: Not downvoting, but not seeing the “big” question here.  I’ve carried all types of laptops for 25+ years in everything from Jansport and Targus at the low end to Tumi and Coach on the upper and never once had these issues.  Now the students and co-workers who used these as frisbees, lunch trays and even make up mirrors, that was a different story, but a case wouldn’t have protected the laptops even then.  I’ve had students leave them on top of cars or under them (yes, they pancaked a MacBook), but it does no good if they aren’t cared for from the onset.

Comment: +1 upvote @Allan you've not seen the issues because you a) respect your equipment, unlike those students and co-workers and b) sometimes additionally you've used high end cases you mention. I do the same. My unfortunate damage to previous Macs as my answer mentioned, was due to accidents rather than rough handling. I can prevent myself from deliberately being rough with equipment but being a human I can't prevent (nor predict!) when I will make honest mistakes: my cases are for those times.

Comment: So as a human, when you park a Hummer on it "by accident" then don't expect any case to save it. And seen 3 colleagues reverse over computers in padded bags like Targus etc (none survived).

Comment: Adding "self answer" and meta / discussion wording to a question will surely draw down votes. **If you review the [tour] we eschew chit chat and prefer direct questions that get right to the point**. People who know will see you are self answering and people that don't will get confused as your intent to answer has nothing constructive to do with the actual problem you face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution**

- Peli 1085 Case for carrying https://www.peli.com/eu/en/product/cases/laptop-case/hardback/1085
- Fintie shell case fitting on mac itself https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0BDRCQKZC

[image: macbook air m2 in fintie case shell on mac itself, and peli carrying case]

No affiliation, referral, incentive or benefit to me.

The Peli 1085 case comes with foam as a grid of cubes that you can push out to make a rectangular cavity that fits around your device.

Some other things I'm looking at: peel on for palm rest and track pad to prevent wear and keyboard protector to help avoid spillage.

I have AppleCare+ which is worth doing but I would want to avoid the hassle in the event of damage.

The Peli 1085 case still fits in a backpack: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07QNNVVP1

I think the above cases are the best for corner protection. An observation I would say about researching them is it took a heck of a long time to get to them, search engines on shops and online are a bit dumb. Terms like Pistol case eventually helped me hone in on what I needed even though that's not what I wanted it for, of course.  Maybe conversational AI will come to the rescue on shopping sites someday.

I also find it amazing that there are so many cases out there that don't focus on the corners - that to me is where dings are going to happen, also when opening the laptop in a confined space with hard material furniture like on a train - the backs of seats on my local service are very hard metal!

All this comes from experience with dinging a MacBookPro 17" 2010 model in a quite padded case. Horrible bent corner causing much distress, so now you can see why I've gone to the lengths I have! These machines are a lot of money so it's worth it.

On a previously owned 2016 MacBookPro 15" I got a UrbanArmourGear/UAG case, very pleased with. I also got a glass screen protector - but would never, ever do that again: it added a moire pattern to the screen. I could take it off to not have that but actually taking of was VERY difficult and caused damage. That Mac's screen was not hard and so lifting the glass screen protector to get it off caused it to pivot into the screen and puncture it with the sharp corners of the glass itself - 600 pounds to repair! Again: NEVER ever get a glass screen protector for your mac on my experience, I think that's going a little too far and will cause unnecessary upset.

Welcoming other answers and as you may have seen recently, I can end up accepting someone elses, while still regarding my own as a useful supplementary.

Being passive cooled, I would be interested on thoughts with snap on cases like the Fintie. I kind of wish someone would make a frame-like case with no panels, just one that fits on the edges and corners, so that there is nothing between the heat transmission of the device and the ambient air.

Comment: The UAG case - have one on my macbook pro as I type - fantastic.

Comment: Do you also wear a crash helmet & seat belt to watch TV in your living room? This is definitely the 'Volvo owner's' solution to a problem.

Comment: I think there's a lot of ego being demonstrated in comments on this post; people are intoxicated by their high scores. Which is a shame.

Comment: Not really. This comes off as a 'product recommendation' just shy of advertising, which tend not to go down well on SE in general. It's also complete overkill. The 'answer' would be 'buy a case' but that really is so obvious no-one would ask it.